# mysqldump confusion

Tags: mysqldump

I must be missing something.  The line I keep seeing everywhere for a consistent backup is:

`mysqldump --single-transaction --all-databases > alldbs.sql`

Yet the MySQL docs indicate `--opt` is on by default. In that is `--lock-tables`.
Also at MySQL docs under `--single-transaction` that the use of `--single-transaction` & `--lock-tables` are mutually exclusive.

It seems to me the command line should be:

```
mysqldump --skip-opt (add in all the ones it uses except --lock-tables) 
    --single-transaction --all-databases >  ....
```

We have production servers that can't be locked for very long; ideally less than a minute.  Any suggestions or can you educate me on what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) states:

> The `--single-transaction` option and the `--lock-tables` option are mutually exclusive because `LOCK TABLES` causes any pending transactions to be committed implicitly.

The code for mysqldump.c has the following near line 963 (MySQL 5.5.33 source code):

```
if (opt_single_transaction || opt_lock_all_tables)
  lock_tables= 0;
```

This is evaluated *after* all defaults have been loaded and command-line options have been parsed.

So even though `--opt` is enabled by default, and therefore it enables `--lock-tables`, this is later changed if you use `--single-transaction`.